# Envio de e-mail com Python e MySQL

Tags: python

Estou tentando enviar e-mails pelo Python com dados de um banco de dados, mais esta ocorrendo um erro que eu não estou conseguindo entender.

O sistema faz a conexão com o banco, envia o primeiro e-mail e quando vai enviar o segundo e-mail da um erro.

Alguem poderia me ajudar com esse código por favor?

Segue o código que tenho:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    import MySQLdb
    import smtplib
    import time

    smtp = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('email-ssl.com.br', 465)
    email = 'intranet@email.com.br'
    senha = '1234'

    # Abre o banco de dados
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","1234","intranet" )

    # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
    cursor = db.cursor()

    sql = " SELECT  e.id,e.email_destino,e.titulo,e.mensagem,e.email_respondepara FROM envia_email e WHERE e.enviado = 'F'"

    try:
       # executa o SQL
       cursor.execute(sql)
       # lista a base.
       results = cursor.fetchall()
       for row in results:
            #id = row[0]
            email_destino = row[1]
            titulo = row[2]
            mensagem = row[3]
            #email_respondepara = row[4]

            time.sleep(40)
            smtp.login(email,senha)

            de = 'intranet@email.com.br'
            para = [email_destino]

            msg = '''Subject: %s \n
            %s''' % (titulo, ' ' + mensagem)

            smtp.sendmail(de, para, msg)
            smtp.quit()
    except:
       print "Error"

    # desconecta do servidor
    db.close()
```

Comment: Qual erro que ocorre?

Comment: ele entra na linha except e imprime Error

Comment: Remova o try .. except para identificar a exceção que está sendo gerada. E todos os registros retornados pelo SQL são válidos?

Comment: Retira o try/catch e vê o erro ao certo sff

Comment: Depois de remover o try, conforme orientação do Andrey e o Miguel, entendi melhor o erro. O sistema estava perdendo conexão com o SMTP. Obrigado pela ajuda!!

Answer (score 0):

Depois da orientação do Andrey e o Miguel arrumei o código e ficou assim:

```
    import MySQLdb
    import smtplib
    import time

    smtp = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('email-ssl.com.br', 465)
    email = 'intranet@email.com.br'
    senha = '1234'

    # Abre o banco de dados
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","1234","intranet" )

    # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
    cursor = db.cursor()

    sql = " SELECT  e.id,e.email_destino,e.titulo,e.mensagem,e.email_respondepara FROM envia_email e WHERE e.enviado = 'F'"

    # executa o SQL
    cursor.execute(sql)
    # lista a base.
    results = cursor.fetchall()

    #loga no SMTP
    smtp.login(email,senha)

    for row in results:
        #id = row[0]
        email_destino = row[1]
        titulo = row[2]
        mensagem = row[3]
        #email_respondepara = row[4]

        #aguarda 20 segundo para enviar o proximo email
        time.sleep(20)

        de = email
        para = [email_destino]

        msg = '''Subject: %s \n
        %s''' % (titulo, ' ' + mensagem)
        #envia o e-mail
        smtp.sendmail(de, para, msg)
    #desconecta do SMTP
    smtp.quit()

    # desconecta do servidor
    db.close()
```